# Stuck on JavaScript koans "about_truthyness" section

Tags: javascript, truthiness

I'm working on Koans by liammclennan and I'm stuck on the "about_truthyness" section with the following code:

```
module("About Truthyness (topics/about_truthyness.js)");

test("truthyness of positive numbers", function() {
    var oneIsTruthy = 1 ? true : false;
    equal(true, oneIsTruthy, 'is one truthy?');
});

test("truthyness of negative numbers", function() {
    var negativeOneIsTruthy = -1 ? true : false;
    equal(true, negativeOneIsTruthy, 'is -1 truthy?');
});

test("truthyness of zero", function() {
    var zeroIsTruthy = 0 ? true : false;
    equal(false, zeroIsTruthy, 'is 0 truthy?');
});

test("truthyness of null", function() {
    var nullIsTruthy = null ? true : false;
    equal(false, nullIsTruthy, 'is null truthy?');
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
About Truthyness (topics/about_truthyness.js): global failure (1, 0, 1)Rerun0 ms
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
Source:     
https://preview.c9users.io/dyczol/koans-javascript/topics/about_assignment.js:11
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. The error says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

So we need to know where the error is. It also says

> Source:
>   https://preview.c9users.io/dyczol/koans-javascript/topics/about_assignment.js:11

So check line 11 and see if there is a ")" missing after an argument list.

Comment: yeah , can't find the right place to put it. line 11 looks just like any others that work fine.